# SwiftData - Predicate does not support keypaths with multiple components

Tags: predicate, swift-data

I have [Word] to [Folder], and Word to Card relationships. I can fetch all words for folder, but i can't fetch all cards for folder. It says Predicate does not support keypaths with multiple components

My Models:

```
@Model
class Word {
  @Attribute(.unique)
  let id: UUID
  
  var title: String
  
  @Relationship(inverse: \Folder.words)
  var folders: [Folder]
  
  @Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade, inverse: \Flashcard.word)
  var flashcard: Flashcard!
}



@Model
class Folder {
  @Attribute(.unique)
  let id: UUID
  
  var title: String
  
  @Relationship
  var words: [Word]
}

@Model
class Flashcard {
  @Attribute(.unique)
  let id: UUID
  
  @Relationship
  var word: Word!
  
  var due: Date
}
```

I can do this fetch, because it build contains instead of build_KeyPaths:

```
  @Query var words: [Word]
  
  init(folder: Folder) {
    self.folder = folder
    
    let fid = folder.id
    
    _words = Query(
      filter: #Predicate<Word> { $0.folders.contains(where: {$0.id == fid})},
      sort: [SortDescriptor(\Word.title, order: .reverse)],
      animation: .default
    )
  }
```

But I can't do even that, not to mention the filtering I need by other fields:

```
  @Query var cards: [Flashcard]
  
  init(folder: Folder) {
    let fid = folder.id
    
    _cards = Query(
      filter: #Predicate<Flashcard> {
        $0.word.folders.contains(where: {$0.id == fid})
      }
    )
  }
```

This predicate is written like this and says that two build_KeyPaths in a row will not work (Fatal error: Predicate does not support keypaths with multiple components)

```
Foundation.Predicate<Flashcard>({
    PredicateExpressions.build_contains(
        PredicateExpressions.build_KeyPath(
            root: PredicateExpressions.build_KeyPath(
                root: PredicateExpressions.build_Arg($0),
                keyPath: \.word
            ),
            keyPath: \.folders
        ),
        where: {
            PredicateExpressions.build_Equal(
                lhs: PredicateExpressions.build_KeyPath(
                    root: PredicateExpressions.build_Arg($0),
                    keyPath: \.id
                ),
                rhs: PredicateExpressions.build_Arg(fid)
            )
        }
    )
    })
```

I can fetch it by folders.words field, but I don't want to do it all in memory, only on the SwiftData side (in predicate), because I have a lot of models. Maybe I wrote the relationships wrong?

I looked  [here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftdata/how-to-filter-swiftdata-results-with-predicates) and it gives examples of filtering by model.relationship.field:

```
@Query(filter: #Predicate<Movie> { movie in
    movie.director.name == "Ridley Scott"
}) var movies: [Movie]
```

But it doesn't work for me.

I can also move all the fields from Flashcard to Word or make the card field an array, but it's look wrong

Comment: I have a similar issue with filtering on properties of a relationship. I finally found out that the predicate only works if the relationship is non optional. Making them non optional unfortunately makes the schema non compatible with CloudKit, which requires all relationships to be optional.